# Webpack + Typescript + watch results in error TS2554 only on re-compilation

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

Software involved:

- webpack 4.8.3
- typescript 2.8.3
- ts-loader 4.3.0

Webpack configuration:

```
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['ng-annotate-loader', 'ts-loader']
    },
    ...
]
```

This compiles my project fine *on a single build* (`webpack --mode development`).

However, it starts to produce errors when building in watch mode:

```
$ webpack --progress --watch --mode development
Webpack is watching the files…

Hash: e8f3fc158b2b6feaad07                                                                  
Version: webpack 4.8.3
Time: 75713ms
Built at: 05/15/2018 3:25:27 PM
          Asset       Size      Chunks             Chunk Names
          ...
```

(The build is fine. Now I change one file, and it rebuilds:)

```
[./ts/foo/foo.ts] 3.82 KiB {foo} [built] [1 error]
[./ts/foo/controllers/bar.ts] 3.8 KiB {baz} {foo} [built]
[./ts/foo/baz.ts] 4.21 KiB {baz} [built] [1 error]
    + 668 hidden modules

ERROR in .../ts/foo/foo.ts
./ts/foo/foo.ts
[tsl] ERROR in .../ts/foo/foo.ts(84,9)
      TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

ERROR in .../ts/foo/baz.ts
./ts/foo/baz.ts
[tsl] ERROR in .../ts/foo/baz.ts(105,9)
      TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
```

The lines it refers to are all lines containing `console.log` calls, e.g.:

```
console.log(`Using locale ${locale}`);
```

Again, if I abort the watch and build from scratch, it works just fine. What's the problem here?

For testing I have removed `ng-annotate-loader`; no change.
This started happening after upgrading the build toolchain from Webpack 3 to 4 with associated upgrades to Typescript from 2.3.x. In the old versions `build --watch` works fine.

Comment: Possible to get a minimal reproducible repo?

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit tricky… :-/ I may try to reproduce that from scratch when I have some time, but for now my generic question would be any hint why a re-build in watch mode would behave any differently at all than a build from scratch. That may help me narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is related to `webpack.NewWatchingPlugin` (the default watching plugin), but you can force webpack to use the old file watching logic if you add new `webpack.OldWatchingPlugin()` plugin. The `OldWatchingPlugin` is more stable than `NewWatchingPlugin`.

There are a variety of reasons why *webpack might not working properly*:

- If no files are outputted (with different hashes), it is likely a configuration issue, not a
  file watching issue.
- Having not enough file watchers causes file watcher in Webpack won't
  recognize the changes.

Comment: Looks like `OldWatchingPlugin` [has been removed a while ago](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commit/e8e541c3fe1b4483c31afb8562956e36c79f0e27)… But I'll try to dick around with the watch plugin settings a bit to see if anything makes any difference.

Comment: @deceze, you might as well rename `d*ck` to `dig` :-)

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution?